# AWS - using p2x.large on free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and I am confused about the usage limits for EC2 instances. I am a free tier user. I want to use p2x.large and I have submitted a request for limit increase. If it gets approved and I use it, will I be charged? Is there is limit up to which it is free?

Comment: It will _not_ be free. If you wish to reduce costs, you could launch it as a [Spot Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cite the official website:

> AWS Free Tier includes 750 hours of both Linux and Windows **t2.micro**
> instances each month for one year for new AWS customers.  To stay
> within the Free Tier, use **only t2.micro** instances.

You can read that on [this](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/p2/?nc1=h_ls) page. The answer to your question is thus yes, you will be charged if you use a p2x.large instance.

Answer (score 2):

AWS free tier include only t2.micro and t3.micro EC2 instances.

In [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc), AWS explains that:

For Linux:

> **750 hours per month** of Linux, RHEL, or SLES **t2.micro or t3.micro** instance dependent on region

and, for Windows instances:

> **750 hours per month** of Windows **t2.micro or t3.micro** instance dependent on region